# MapReduce or aggregation framework?

Tags: mongodb

As I understand, both aggregation framework and MapReduce have the same goal, but my question is, when should I use MapReduce and when aggregation framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map reduce is really good for long standing aggregation tasks which might take anywhere between 10 minutes - 10 hours (or more) to complete.

Imagine the aggregation framework as being similar in kind to SQLs own with the operators like `GROUP`.

It is really designed for quick inline querying to return a result back however, map reduce is for much larger jobs and is not designed for inline usage.

Answer (score 1):

aggregation framework has limitations over sharded collections, where you will have to use MapReduce.

Comment: What limitations would that be?

Comment: @Sammaye, http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-sharded-collections/

Comment: I do not see any limitations on that page

Answer (score 1):

Refer: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/

My understanding is that when you are dealing with large quantities of data, MapReduce will perform much better as compared to Aggregation framework.